# Why does adding the requested cab file still not show exception details?

Tags: debugging, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-1.1, handheld

I was getting an exception that was being coy about its innards, but was still forthcoming enough to divulge this: *exception in PopulateControlsIfVendorItemsFound() == An err msg is available for this exception but cannout be displayed...Please install 'NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab' for Windows Mobile 5.0 and above or 'NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab' for other platforms...*

So I searched for "NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab" on my dev machine, so that I could copy it to the handheld device, but it was not found. I found it on the Interwebs, and deployed it to the handheld device (in the same folder where the .exe throwing the exception lives), but still was getting the same only semi-informative meta-exception message shown above.

Is it in the wrong place? Is it perchance the wrong file?

Comment: It sounds like you are compiling or using some control that expects *NETCFv35*. That won't work in your `.net-1.1` world.

Comment: I've seen this behavior before as well.  Even with the cab in place it wasn't giving the textual exception messages.